# GnuPG retorna false no PHP

Tags: php

Estou usando o módulo [GnuPG](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) no PHP e testei exatamente com este código:

```
$keydata = '-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0
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=p4Wt
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----';

$res = gnupg_init();
$info = gnupg_import($res,$keydata);
var_dump($info);
```

> **Esta chave privada foi gerada para testes!**

Resultado:

```
bool(false)
```

Eu testei com esta chave acima e também com o chave "original", ambas apresentam o `$info` como `false`, o que não é o esperado. Segunda a documentação (e o comentário de 9 anos atrás) em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gnupg-import.php era para ser exibido informações sobre a chave que foi importada.

Nenhum erro é informado nos logs e o módulo está instalado corretamente e com todas as dependências necessárias, aparentemente.

Essa extensão não funciona mais ou há algo errado?

Comment: Adicionei a tag, pois não é algo nativo, assim ajuda evitar confusão de quem vier responder ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui uma solução. :D

**Causa do problema:**

O PHP/NGINX não estava conseguindo acessar a pasta onde é importado o arquivo e por isso era apresentado `false`.

Experimente executar o mesmo *script* como *root* usando o *PHP-CLI* e provavelmente não irá apresentar o problema.

**Solução:**

Entre numa pasta fora do acesso da web:

```
cd /usr
```

Crie uma pasta por exemplo:

```
mkdir .nomelegal
```

Dê a permissão para o NGINX:

```
chown -R nginx .nomelegal
chgrp -R nginx .nomelegal
```

Se estiver usando o Apache troque o `nginx` por `www-data`, acredito que seja isso.

Depois disso determine o local no PHP adicionando isso:

```
<?php

putenv("GNUPGHOME=/usr/.nomelegal");
```

```
$keydata = '...';

$res = gnupg_init();
$info = gnupg_import($res,$keydata);
var_dump($info);
```

Se tudo estiver certo agora o PHP é capaz de ler e escrever dentro da pasta e assim poderá importar as chaves publicas e privadas!

**Nota:**

Não sei se é necessário, mas o Centos não executa o gpg-agent automaticamente, portanto deverá executar:

```
gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket
```

*Isso foi usado para possibilitar gerar chaves, não sei se é necessário para o GnuPG no PHP.*

Comment: Entendi, o problema era a permissão de grupo, o que impedia a leitura e escrita se vindo do nginx. Um ideia, tenho quase certeza que é possivel cadastrar o comando `gpg-agent --daemon --use-standard-socket` no arranque https://support.suso.com/supki/CentOS_Init_startup_scripts

Comment: Eu tinha pensando em fazer isso, mas não consegui fazer :< Irei tentar com mais calma depois.